# How to run NPM using a specific Node interpreter?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have an Electron project that uses native libraries, some of which have prebuilds that get downloaded during `npm install`. This grabs the prebuilds for the global Node version running NPM, which isn't quite what I need. Is there a way to execute NPM explicitly using the Electron binary in my project?

Comment: no, `electron-rebuild` or other similar post-rebuild tools are made to solve those behavior.

Comment: @OJKwon They don’t load prebuilds; many libraries do have Electron / NAPI prebuilds available which solve this except a lot faster, but the prebuild downloader will fetch the most specific available one for the current runtime; and grpc is extremely fiddly to build from source, their documentation explicitly recommends sticking to their comprehensive hoard of prebuilda.

Comment: Right now my builds work mostly because I have a working grpc binding file somewhere in a cache from when the stars were aligned properly; and they broke for macOS Catalina where I’m saved by not actually needing grpc on macOS right now. This is a sad state of affairs I’d rather not adress by trying to figure out how to cajole a very complicated library into compiling against its maintainers’s advice.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't downloads prebuilds maching abi for electron but my point stands still: no npm doesn't offer to specify custom node binary unless you manually patch internal.